# preg_replace dynamic replacement don't work as expected

Tags: php

I have some problems with the fottowing code:

```
echo preg_replace('/^([@\.]*)$/i', '<span>$1</span>', "example@mail.com");
```

I want to get `example<span>@</span>mail<span>.</span>com"`, but with `$1` I'm not getting the value I need... any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, **it works**

```
echo preg_replace('/([@\.])/i', '<span>$1</span>', "example@mail.com");
```

Comment: what was wrong with `^` and `$`, aren't they correct?

Comment: ^ means the string must begin with @ or . AND $ means the string must end with @ or .